# Appropriate concat for dataframes of different size

Tags: python, pandas

I have some dataframes of different row size (columns are the same) and I want to calculate the sum of each column in the last row and then combine them in one dataframe.

I'm using this function:

```
def day_sum(tot_df):

week_days = ['MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA', 'SU', 'Total']
week = []
for this_day in week_days:
    day = tot_df[tot_df['DayColumn'] == this_day]
    day = day.append(day.sum(numeric_only=False), ignore_index=True)
    day.loc[day.index[-1], 'Value'] = 'Total'
    day.loc[day.index[-1], 'DayColumn'] = this_day
    week.append(day)
df = pd.concat(week, ignore_index=True)
return df
```

This is what I get:

```
(tot_df)
index  Column1  Column2  Column3
    0      3        2        3
    1      4        3        4
    2      7        4        5
    3      4        5        6
    sum    18
    sum             14
    sum                      20
```

This is what I need:

```
(tot_df)
index  Column1  Column2  Column3
    0      3        2        3
    1      4        3        4
    2      7        4        5
    3      4        5        6
    sum    18       14      20
```

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening or merge the "sum" rows in the end?
Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your code just use:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = ['sum'] + df[df.columns[1:]].sum(0).tolist()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case. Is there maybe any specific fix for my code?

Comment: It just gives me the sum of the first column and ignores the rest

Comment: @Emanon Are you using the same dataframe?

Comment: Yes I'm using the same.